# Minimum number of colors to paint a map

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

Given a planar graph such that all its vertices are of degree 4, find the minimum number of colors needed to paint the map.

I've used the Euler formula for graphs $$v-e+f=2$$ where $$v$$ is the number of vertices, $$e$$ is edges and $$f$$ is the number of faces in the plane. Because the sum of all vertices' degrees of a graph equals to $$2e$$, I get $$4v=2e\Rightarrow f=2+v$$

I can't attach pics, but for 1 to 3 vertices it clearly only takes 3 colors. My question is, how to prove that it's true for arbitrary number of vertices, if it is?

Comment: If all the vertices are of degree $4$, wouldn't you need at least $5$ vertices?  (or in fact $6$, as Servaes has pointed out)

Comment: @Henry There are many such planar graphs, but the smallest has $6$ vertices. And clearly you will need at least $5$ colors if the graph is nonempty.

Comment: @Servaes - Thank you - I have edited my comment

Comment: Every self-loop increases the degree of a vertex by 2 AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the question asks for a colouring of the faces. In this case, the  map can be coloured with only two colours. It is a bit like a checkerboard. This is actually true for any graph where all the vertices are of even degree (not necessarily all the same).

I don't know the best way to prove this, but you could do it by induction on the number of edges. Given a graph with even degree vertices, select any loop of edges from that graph. If you were to remove that loop, the vertices involved reduce their degree by 2, so remain of even degree. You are left with a graph with fewer edges, which still has all vertices of even degree. By the induction hypothesis its faces can be 2-coloured. You can now add the loop back in, and flip the colours of the area inside the loop to get a 2-colouring of the original map. As the base case(s) for the induction you can take the graphs with no edges, and any number of vertices of degree 0.

Comment: I still think I need a 3rd color to paint the map outside of the faces which are surrounded by edges. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MehMech Are you sure your vertices around the outside are all of degree 4?

Comment: for v=1 I have 1 vertice with two self-loops, hence degree 4. 1 self-loop per vertice for v=2.

Comment: @MehMech For your v=1 example, the interior of the two loops can have the same colour since they do not share boundary edge, and the outside can then be the second colour.

Comment: checked for some other big v's, look convincing. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, in the previous comment about the v=1 example with two loops I assumed the two loops were disjoint. The loops can instead be drawn one inside the other, and then you will need a different colouring, but two colours is still sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If a $4$-regular graph is nonempty then clearly its chromatic number will be at least $5$. There exists a $4$-regular-planar graph of order $6$ with chromatic number $5$, so the minimum number of colors needed is $5$.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in your answer. All planar graphs, $4$-regular or otherwise, have chromatic number at most $4$, no?

Comment: I think Servaes is confusing edge coloring and vertex coloring. A 4-regular graph with $6$ vertices is actually 3-colorable. And as Misha Lavrov said, 4-color Theorem states that every planar graph is 4-colorable.

Comment: The graph divides the plane into a number of connected areas. I thought this was the map I need to color.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, the 4-color theorem implies the graph is 4-colorable.  The question is probably whether such graphs are 3-colorable.  $K_4$ requires four colors but is not 4-regular.